# Error while reading XML from blob Container mycontainer in account .blob.core.windows.net not found

Tags: xml, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I use the following to read xml
val df = spark.read
.option("rowTag", "testing")
.xml(xmlpath)
xmlpath is a wasbs://mycontainer@.blob.core.windows.net/
but it has the following error
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container mycontainer in account .blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
what's happening

I put the same file to another blob account, the code run successfully . I don't know what happen to that blob account.

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, I think your SAS token is not working. An easy way to create a SAS token is by using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information on how to connect Azure blob, please refer to [this doc](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) or the code below.

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.sas.<your-container-name>.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<the query string you copy>") 

dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
```

Expected output :

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The XML-lib uses the RDD API. Hadoop configuration options set using spark.conf.set(...) are not accessible via SparkContext. This means that while they are visible to the DataFrame and Dataset API, they are not visible to the RDD API. If you are using the RDD API to read from Azure Blob Storage, you must set the credentials, e. g. on the Cluster Level/Advanced Options/Spark in the cluster config:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.aseursvgspasasandbox380.blob.core.windows.net <storage-key>
```

See also the [Azure Databricks Documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#access-azure-blob-storage-directly) Section: Access Azure Blob Storage using the RDD API.

Comment: I think this explaination is correct.  Let me try later. Coz when I map the blob as a mount point , the library is working

Comment: where to type the following command ?
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.aseursvgspasasandbox380.blob.core.windows.net <storage-key>

Comment: You can do this on the cluster level, under advanced options, spark config